# I want to draw draggable JComponent on background image

Tags: java, swing, components, draggable, drag

There are code that one is a Zoo, the other is animal(tiger and eagle are same code now, so i just write Tiger.java). 
I want to draw draggable JComponent on background image. Draggable JComponent was worked on the frame, not image. First, I click on image then draw my animal, Second, after i draw many animal, I can drag and drop my animal anywhere on image. Please teach me how to draw.

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class BgPanel extends JPanel
{
    Image bg = new ImageIcon("c:\\back.jpg").getImage();
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(bg,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
    }
}

public class Zoo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Container c;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JComboBox comBox = new JComboBox();
    drawCanvas can = new drawCanvas();
    saving_drawing saving=new saving_drawing();
    Tiger tiger;
    Eagle eagle;
    Point point;

    ArrayList<saving_drawing> arr_saving = new ArrayList();

    Zoo()
    {
        JPanel bgPanel = new BgPanel();
        bgPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        comBox.addItem("Tiger");
        comBox.addItem("Eagle");
        comBox.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setContentPane(bgPanel);

        bgPanel.add(comBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bgPanel.add(can, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Zoo");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if("Tiger".equals(comBox.getSelectedItem()))
        {
              saving.drawChoice=1;
        }
        else if("Eagle".equals(comBox.getSelectedItem()))
        {
              saving.drawChoice=2;
        }

    }
    class drawCanvas extends JComponent
    {
        public drawCanvas()
        {
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    count++;
                    if(count!=0)
                    {
                    saving.point=e.getPoint();

                    arr_saving.add(new saving_drawing(saving.drawChoice,saving.point));
                    repaint();
                    System.out.println("click");
                    }
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
            });
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                saving.drawChoice=arr_saving.get(i).drawChoice;
                saving.point=arr_saving.get(i).point;

                if(saving.drawChoice==1)
                {
                    tiger=new Tiger(saving.point);
                    //frame.add(tiger);
                    //frame.setVisible(true);
                    //tiger.draw(g2);
                    //can.add(tiger);
                    tiger.paintComponent(g2);
                    //I'don't know what to do for drawing my tiger
                }
                if(saving.drawChoice==2)
                {
                    eagle=new Eagle(saving.point);
                    eagle.draw(g2);
                }

            }

        }
    }
    class saving_drawing
    {
        int drawChoice;

        Point point;
        saving_drawing(){}
        saving_drawing(int dc, Point p)
        {
            this.drawChoice = dc;
            this.point=p;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Zoo test = new Zoo();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
public class Tiger extends JComponent implements MouseListener
{
     private boolean draggable = true;

        protected Cursor draggingCursor = Cursor
               .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
        protected boolean overbearing = false;

    save_drawing save = new save_drawing();

    Tiger(Point point)
    {

        save.point=point;


        addMouseListener(this);
        addDragListeners();
        setOpaque(true);

    }
    private void addDragListeners()

    {


        final Tiger handle = this;

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()

        {
           public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)

           {

               save.point = e.getPoint();

           setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

           }
           public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)

           {

               int anchorX = save.point.x;

               int anchorY = save.point.y;
               Point parentOnScreen = getParent().getLocationOnScreen();

               Point mouseOnScreen = e.getLocationOnScreen();

               Point position = new Point(mouseOnScreen.x - parentOnScreen.x

                       - anchorX, mouseOnScreen.y - parentOnScreen.y - anchorY);

               setLocation(position);

               if (overbearing)

               {

                   getParent().setComponentZOrder(handle, 0);
                   System.out.println("check");
                   repaint();

               }

           }

        });

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (isOpaque())

        {
           g.setColor(Color.black);
           g.fillRect(save.point.x, save.point.y, 50, 50);
        }

    }
    class save_drawing
    {
        Point point;


    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {

        save.point=e.getPoint();

        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
     private void removeDragListeners()

        {
            for (MouseMotionListener listener : this.getMouseMotionListeners())
            {
               removeMouseMotionListener(listener);
            }
            setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dragging components around a panel you can use the [Component Mover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/).